# How to debug Behat/Selenium when javascript action is not executed?

Tags: javascript, php, selenium, debugging, behat

I've got some element on the site

```
<div id="checkout">
  <a href="" onclick="submitHostedPage('z_hppm_iframe'); return false;">Submit</a>
</div>
```

which is perfectly OK (clickable) in the browser or could be reached and executed from the console by `document.querySelector("#checkout > a").click()`

The target javascript method normally submits iframe which is coming from the third party external side and everything seems to be OK with that.

Now when I'm trying to execute this click or actually run directly the target javascript method I've got no positive response Behat (step has passed) but actually the script is not executed. There should be some validation errors visible or the checkout form sumitted and next page loaded.

Any idea how to debug this?

When I execute Behat step

```
Then I click on element "#checkoutSummary > a"
```

The log from Selenium (Docker container) looks like that

```
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,438 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.437 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.xpath: //html/descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'checkoutSummary']/a])
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,449 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.449 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.xpath: //html/descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'checkoutSummary']/a]
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,451 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.451 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.xpath: (//html/descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'checkoutSummary']/a)[1]])
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,461 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.461 INFO - Done: [find element: By.xpath: (//html/descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'checkoutSummary']/a)[1]]
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,463 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.462 INFO - Executing: [mousemove: 46 false])
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,491 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.490 INFO - Done: [mousemove: 46 false]
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,493 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.492 INFO - Executing: [click: 46 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (65a37ed4-e04f-47ec-89fa-d007b2173b54)] -> xpath: //html/descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'checkoutSummary']/a]])
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,554 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.554 INFO - Done: [click: 46 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (65a37ed4-e04f-47ec-89fa-d007b2173b54)] -> xpath: //html/descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'checkoutSummary']/a]]
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,559 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.559 INFO - Executing: [set window size])
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,567 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.567 INFO - Done: [set window size]
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,570 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.570 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,575 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.575 INFO - Done: [get current url]
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,590 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.589 INFO - Executing: [take screenshot])
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,728 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.728 INFO - Done: [take screenshot]
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,845 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.845 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 5cfca9c7-e13d-472e-a5bb-4d25ac2ae6bf])
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-15 10:14:33,917 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 10:14:33.916 INFO - Done: [delete session: 5cfca9c7-e13d-472e-a5bb-4d25ac2ae6bf]
```

Taking a screenshot is just a confirmation that something went wrong as the current URL is not the one which was expected.

I've also tried to execute js directly from Behat which seemed to work as I can see this in the following output in Selenium log but there are no results of any javascript script execution/actions either.

```
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-14 14:40:58,776 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 14:40:58.776 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return submitHostedPage('z_hppm_iframe');, []])
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-14 14:40:58,786 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 14:40:58.785 INFO - Done: [execute script: return submitHostedPage('z_hppm_iframe');, []]
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-14 14:40:58,892 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 14:40:58.892 INFO - Executing: [set window size])
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-14 14:40:58,899 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 14:40:58.899 INFO - Done: [set window size]
selenium_1  |
selenium_1  | 2017-06-14 14:40:58,902 DEBG 'selenium' stderr output:
selenium_1  | 14:40:58.902 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return false;, []])
```

Any suggestions really appreciated.

Comment: You are expecting an error from behat, right? What is the next step after the click? Maybe the problem is with this next step...

Comment: The next step should be landing on another page on successful submission of form which is not happening. Also when I modify some of the previous steps to skip filling the required field I should js validation error instantly which is not happening.

Comment: As i see from the last log the script is executed and returns false. What you need to provide is the code behind the step and the stack-trace of the exception if any. If the script fails in any way it is possible that will not throw any exception if the element is not found, it will only throw exception if the driver does not support the operation. Please make sure the element is there before executing the script.